# What's killing my apricot tree?

Tags: diseases, tree-care

bought my house a few month ago, the apricot tree in the garden seemed fine at first and I thought it would be ok because a lot of buds appeared early, but now it seems to be dying.

Do you think it was the frost or some fungus?

Should I cut all dying branches?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because some branches look good, while others are dying, it could be borers in the dead branches. Some borers produce waste/frass at a hole. Surface insecticide will not reach them. I have killed some by inserting a wire into the hole, if you can find the holes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have grass growing all the way up to the trunk - the grass competes with the tree for water and nutrients. Ideally, the tree should be centred on a circle of bare soil around 1-1.2 metre diameter. The easiest way to do this is to spray a circle off using Roundup. To [quote](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/types/trees/planting-trees-shrubs) from the RHS:

> Keep a vegetation-free circle at least 1.2m (4ft) in diameter around
> the plant for its first three years to help avoid this problem.
>
> The circle can be kept weed free through hoeing, using a mulching mat
> or use of contact or systemic weedkillers.
>
> Laying mulch over this circle is also helpful, although take care to
> leave a collar of 10cm (4in) around the woody stems that is free of
> mulch, to prevent the risk of rotting the bark.

Comment: Doesn't grass only drain surface moisture? Furthermore doesn't it prevent the sun hitting the soil directly thus reducing moisture loss? At lest mulch does.